# Installing haskell platform fails

Tags: haskell-platform

I am trying to install haskell-platform-2011.2.0.1 onto my suse 11.4. I have got the all the dependencies required for the ./configure with works ok. But on getting to "make", it builds with this error

```
scripts/build.sh
**************************************************
Scanning system for any installed Haskell Platform components...

Found:None.

New packages to install: None! All done.

**************************************************
Building transformers-0.2.2.0
"/usr/bin/ghc" "--make" "Setup" "-o" "Setup" "-package" "Cabal"
Linking Setup ...
"./Setup" "configure" "--package-db=../../packages/package.conf.inplace" "--prefix=/usr/local" "--with-compiler=/usr/bin/ghc" "--with-hc-pkg=/usr/bin/ghc-pkg" "--with-hsc2hs=/usr/bin/hsc2hs" "--enable-library-profiling" "--ghc-pkg-option=--package-conf=../../packages/package.conf.inplace"
Configuring transformers-0.2.2.0...
"./Setup" "build"
Preprocessing library transformers-0.2.2.0...
Building transformers-0.2.2.0...

Control/Monad/IO/Class.hs:19:7:
    Could not find module `System.IO':
      Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package `base'?
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Error:
Building the transformers-0.2.2.0 package failed
make: *** [build.stamp] Error 2
```

I have googled around but not one seems to have the right solution. How do install the missing 'System.IO' module?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the problem was likely that the ghc package used for the build did not have profiling libraries included.